# BucketIterator not returning batches of correct size

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, torchtext

I'm implementing a simple LSTM language model in `PyTorch`, and wanted to check out the `BucketIterator` that is provided by `torchtext`.

It turns out that the batch that is returned has the size of my entire corpus, so I must be doing something wrong during its initialisation.

I've already got the `BPTTIterator` working, but as I want to be able to train on batches of complete sentences as well, I thought the `BucketIterator` should be the way to go.

I use the following setup, with my corpus a simple txt file containing sentences at each line.

```
field = Field(use_vocab=True, batch_first=True)
corpus = PennTreebank('project_2_data/train_lines.txt', field)
field.build_vocab(corpus)

iterator = BucketIterator(corpus,
                          batch_size=64,
                          repeat=False,
                          sort_key=lambda x: len(x.text),
                          sort_within_batch=True,
                          )
```

I expect a batch from this iterator to have the shape `(batch_size, max_len)`, but it appends the entire corpus into 1 tensor of shape `(1, corpus_size)`.

What am I missing in my setup?

Edit: it seems the `PennTreebank` object is not compatible with a `BucketIterator` (it contains only 1 `Example` as noted here http://mlexplained.com/2018/02/15/language-modeling-tutorial-in-torchtext-practical-torchtext-part-2/). Using a `TabularDataset` with only 1 `Field` got it working.

If someone has an idea how language modelling with padded sentence batches can be done in `torchtext` in a more elegant manner I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Same issue here.